# Request Topic vs Create New Topic

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

When try to create a non existing topic, users are given two options: 'Request Topic' and 'Create New Topic'. What is the difference between these two options? Which one should be opted in which situation?

Comment: The former is request from others … The latter is creating it yourself.

Comment: @bwoebi Why would I use *Request Topic* when I can directly create it?

Comment: You perhaps only have limited time for covering everything yourself? Then you request a topic and hope someone will have the muse to write it sometime.